# Load Teradata table from Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, teradatasql, pandas-to-sql

I am getting below error while trying to load Teradata table from Python Pandas,  Any idea ?
teradatasql and pandas - writing dataframe into TD table - Error 3707 - Syntax error, expected something like '(' between the 'type' keyword and '='

```
import teradatasql
import pandas as pd
 
 conTD = teradatasql.connect(host=Host, user=User, password=Passwd, logmech="LDAP", encryptdata="true")
 df.to_sql(tableName, conTD, schema=schemaName, if_exists='fail', index=False)
```

Comment: Does your dataframe have a column named `type`? That's a reserved keyword. You could change the name to something else. Or consider using teradatasqlalchemy and pass an "engine" using the teradatasql dialect to `to_sql` in place of passing a "connection" directly.